# Include FTPUTIL library on web2py

Tags: python, web2py, ftputil

Does FTPUTIL library included on web2py? if not, how to include that library. I think because it is so useful in creating ftp client.thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ftputil is not included in web2py. If you are running web2py from source, you can just install ftputil as you normally would and import in your app code. If running the web2py binary, you might be able to just copy the ftputil folder into /web2py/site-packages.

Comment: Make sure you have Python installed. Then just [download](http://web2py.com/init/default/download) the source version of web2py and unzip. To start the built-in server, change to the /web2py directory and type `python web2py.py`.

Comment: im just running the web2py.exe to start creating/updating my applications. is that what you called binary?

Comment: Yes, that's the Windows binary.